# How can overlapping NFS permissions be configured?

Tags: permissions, solaris, nfs

I am running Solaris 10 on my NFS server.  I am struggling with how to setup read-only access to a share from a subnet, but allow read-write access from a system within that subnet.

On the Server:

```
root@server># share -F nfs -o log,root=192.168.10.10,rw=192.168.10.10,ro=@192.168.1/24 /export/plaground
```

The read-write client is able to mount the share, but is not able to write, either as root or a standard user with permissions to the share...

```
root@client># mount server:/export/playground /mnt
root@client># mount
<snip>
server:/export/playground on /mnt type nfs (rw,addr=192.168.168.5)
root@client># ls -axl /mnt
total 90
drwxr-xr-x+ 25 root root    25 Nov  2 11:45 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 Nov  2 11:28 ..
drwxrwxr-x   2 root users    2 Nov  2 11:45 test
root@client># touch /mnt/file.test
touch: cannot touch `/mnt/file.test': Read-only file system
root@client># exit
user@client>$ touch /mnt/test/file.test
touch: cannot touch `/mnt/test/file.test': Read-only file system
```

I have attempted to adjust the order of the options, but to no success.  Putting the read-only option prior to the read-write option does nothing to change the status of the mount.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Answer...

```
root@server># share -F nfs -o log,root=@192.168.10.10/32,rw=@192.168.10.10/32,ro=@192.168.1/24 /export/playground
```

For single IP's you must do the @IP/32, for proper cidr notation.